# Change the directory of DataContext database file in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql

I am trying to change the location of the database file in my Windows Phone 8 app.

The default constructor places it in the root isolated storage directory: `/MyDbFile.sdf/`

```
public MyDataContext() : base("Data Source=isostore:/MyDbFile.sdf") { }
```

My goal is to put it in `/db/MyDbFile.sdf`

What I have tried (yes, I know that some of them are silly):

```
public MyDataContext() : base("Data Source=isostore:/db/MyDbFile.sdf") { }
public MyDataContext() : base("Data Source=isostore:/db\\MyDbFile.sdf") { }
public MyDataContext() : base("Data Source=isostore:\\db/MyDbFile.sdf") { }
public MyDataContext() : base("Data Source=isostore:\\/db/MyDbFile.sdf") { }
public MyDataContext() : base("Data Source=isostore:/db//MyDbFile.sdf") { }
public MyDataContext() : base("Data Source=isostore:/db\\/MyDbFile.sdf") { }
```

What is the proper way to do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it right after writing this question. You have to create the target directory first.

```
using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (!iso.DirectoryExists("db"))
    {
        iso.CreateDirectory("db");
    }
}
_MyDataContext = new MyDataContext();
```

After that it works with:

```
public MyDataContext() : base("Data Source=isostore:/db/MyDbFile.sdf") { }
```